# Div not getting correct height with img content

Tags: css, html, image

I have a simple page with a single div. Inside that div I have an image with dimensions [h:58px, w:173px].

```
<body>
    <div id="main_header">
        <img src="logo.gif" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
    </div>
</body>
```

It is not wrapped in any other tags. However, Chrome calculates the height of the container div as 63px. There is no associated css with the #main_header. html and body both have margin and padding set to 0.

Can anyone explain why the div's height is coming out to 63 and not 58?

Comment: if you inspect the element in dev tools you can scroll down the list of css to see if there are any rogue css being applied to the element. body and html are not the only things that can mess things up

Comment: this is a CSS issue. Use chrome dev tools to inspect styles. Disable styles as a process of elimination.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the parent's `line-height`. Either set the `line-height` (or `font-size`) of the parent to zero, or set the image to `display: block`.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. It ended up being that the image was being assigned "display: inline-block" from the user-agent stylesheet. display:block fixed it!